# Site to ask about legality of school's community service policy

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about the legality of my school's community service policy. (Presumably it *is* legal, but I want to be sure before I go and do a bunch of stuff..

What site would be the best for this question? I considered Law, but I don't really know the rules there and figured I'd ask if there was a better alternative before just going there and asking.

---

The question more specifically:

My school has a clause regarding community service done for "religiously affiliated organizations or events" and states that they won't accept service for any of them. Is this legal, (if not) what could I do about it, other than filing a lawsuit against my school?

Comment: Why not ask on Law's meta whether this would be an acceptable question? Or alternatively just ask your school why they have this rule.

Comment: @RobertLongson [done](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/602/would-this-be-an-acceptable-question-here)

Comment: The Law SE has a help center, you state you don't know the rules for that website, go read it then you will

Comment: An organization is free to define what will and will not be community service if in the confines of an requirement

Comment: It would probably be helpful to explain what your question *means*. Could you quote the clause? What would it mean to accept (or refuse) service? What kind of services are you talking about? Also what jurisdiction you are in is likely to be a big factor, along with things like whether it's a state or private school.

Comment: @Ramhound It depends on whether it's a private institution (yes) or a public one (debatably not on 1st amendment grounds).

Comment: @Won't - I suppose;  I would argue, that even a publically funded school, would have the ability to define what will be considered to be community service though.  Of course I would expect those rules, would vary from district to district, depending involvement of the community.  I don't believe a ruling like, Everson v. Board of Education, would apply to a school accepting a certain type of community service as community service.  *1st admendment only applies to congress.*

Comment: @Ramhound not to turn this into an extended off topic discussion, but the 1st amendment is the law of the land, and applies to every government body at every level (see the supremacy clause). The debatable part comes when a judge interprets the action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Law SE seems to be the best site for this question, as proven by [this question](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/602/would-this-be-an-acceptable-question-here). I have since, posted the question there.